# go channels with kafka consumer

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I'm new to go and starting to learn about channels. I'm using the confluent kafka consumer to create a functional consumer. What I want to accomplish is to send the messages into a buffered channel (2,000)...and then write the messages in the channel to redis using pipeline. I've gotten to consumer part to work by just doing a `println` of the message one by one until it reaches the end of the offsets, but when I try to add a channel, it seems to hit the `default:` case in the `switch` and then just freeze.

it also doesn't look like I'm filling the channel correctly? This `fmt.Println("count is: ", len(redisChnl))` always prints `0`

here is what I have so far:

```
// Example function-based high-level Apache Kafka consumer
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
    "regexp"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    "encoding/binary"
)

var client *redis.Client

func init() {
    client = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:         ":6379",
        DialTimeout:  10 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  30 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
        PoolSize:     10,
        PoolTimeout:  30 * time.Second,
    })
    client.FlushDB()
}

type MessageFormat struct {
    MetricValueNumber float64     `json:"metric_value_number"`
    Path              string      `json:"path"`
    Cluster           string      `json:"cluster"`
    Timestamp         time.Time   `json:"@timestamp"`
    Version           string      `json:"@version"`
    Host              string      `json:"host"`
    MetricPath        string      `json:"metric_path"`
    Type              string      `json:"string"`
    Region            string      `json:"region"`
}

//func redis_pipeline(ky string, vl string) {
//  pipe := client.Pipeline()
//
//  exec := pipe.Set(ky, vl, time.Hour)
//
//  incr := pipe.Incr("pipeline_counter")
//  pipe.Expire("pipeline_counter", time.Hour)
//
//  // Execute
//  //
//  //     INCR pipeline_counter
//  //     EXPIRE pipeline_counts 3600
//  //
//  // using one client-server roundtrip.
//  _, err := pipe.Exec()
//  fmt.Println(incr.Val(), err)
//  // Output: 1 <nil>
//}

func main() {


    sigchan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigchan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    c, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers":               "kafka.com:9093",
        "group.id":                        "testehb",
        "security.protocol":               "ssl",
        "ssl.key.location":                "/Users/key.key",
        "ssl.certificate.location":        "/Users/cert.cert",
        "ssl.ca.location":                 "/Users/ca.pem",
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Failed to create consumer: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Created Consumer %v\n", c)

    err = c.SubscribeTopics([]string{"jmx"}, nil)

    redisMap := make(map[string]string)

    redisChnl := make(chan []byte, 2000)

    run := true

    for run == true {
        select {
        case sig := <-sigchan:
            fmt.Printf("Caught signal %v: terminating\n", sig)
            run = false
        default:
            ev := c.Poll(100)
            if ev == nil {
                continue
            }

            switch e := ev.(type) {
            case *kafka.Message:

                //fmt.Printf("%% Message on %s:\n%s\n",
                //  e.TopicPartition, string(e.Value))
                if e.Headers != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("%% Headers: %v\n", e.Headers)
                }

                str := e.Value
                res := MessageFormat{}
                json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)


                fmt.Println("size", binary.Size([]byte(str)))

                host:= regexp.MustCompile(`^([^.]+)`).FindString(res.MetricPath)

                redisMap[host] = string(str)
                fmt.Println("count is: ", len(redisChnl)) //this always prints "count is:  0"

                redisChnl <- e.Value //I think this is the write way to put the messages in the channel?

            case kafka.PartitionEOF:
                fmt.Printf("%% Reached %v\n", e)
            case kafka.Error:
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% Error: %v\n", e)
                run = false
            default:
                fmt.Printf("Ignored %v\n", e)
            }

            <- redisChnl // I thought I could just empty the channel like this once the buffer is full?


        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("Closing consumer\n")
    c.Close()
}
```

-------EDIT-------

Ok, I think I got it to work by moving the `<- redisChnl` inside `default`, but now I see that the `count before read` and `count after read` inside the `default` always prints `2,000`...I would have thought that the first `count before read = 2,000` and then `count after read = 0` since the channel would be empty then??

```
    select {
    case sig := <-sigchan:
        fmt.Printf("Caught signal %v: terminating\n", sig)
        run = false
    default:
        ev := c.Poll(100)
        if ev == nil {
            continue
        }

        switch e := ev.(type) {
        case *kafka.Message:

            //fmt.Printf("%% Message on %s:\n%s\n",
            //  e.TopicPartition, string(e.Value))
            if e.Headers != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%% Headers: %v\n", e.Headers)
            }

            str := e.Value
            res := MessageFormat{}
            json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)


            //fmt.Println("size", binary.Size([]byte(str)))

            host:= regexp.MustCompile(`^([^.]+)`).FindString(res.MetricPath)

            redisMap[host] = string(str)

            go func() {
                redisChnl <- e.Value
            }()


        case kafka.PartitionEOF:
            fmt.Printf("%% Reached %v\n", e)
        case kafka.Error:
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% Error: %v\n", e)
            run = false
        default:
            fmt.Println("count before read: ", len(redisChnl))

            fmt.Printf("Ignored %v\n", e)

            <-redisChnl

            fmt.Println("count after read: ", len(redisChnl)) //would've expected this to be 0

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger way to simplify this code is to separate the pipeline into multiple goroutines.

The advantage of channels is the multiple people can be writing and reading on them at the same time. In this example, this might mean having a single go routine enqueueing onto the channel and another pulling off of the channel and putting things into redis.

Something like this:

```
c := make(chan Message, bufferLen)
go pollKafka(c)
go pushToRedis(c)
```

If you want to add batching, you could add a middle stage that polls from the kafka channel, and appends to a slice until the slice is full and then enqueues that slice onto the channel for redis.

If concurrency like this isn't a goal, it might be just be easier to replace the channel in your code with a slice. If there is only ever 1 goroutine acting on an object, it's not a good idea to try and use a channel.

Comment: ok...I was under the assumption that if I used a buffered channel of lets say size `2,000`, I could put 2,000 messages in it and then read them into another go routine? The reason for this is that it looks like the confluent kafka consumer will poll but has a max off one message? https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/f5a17f16c36bc1505cd0c1a7f9c96c42387d75e7/kafka/consumer.go#L257...so what I wanted to do was keep polling until I get 2,000 messages, then batch write those to redis

Comment: It is possible to do what you said, but if you are only looping with a single routine from kafka, why not put those events in a slice instead of a channel? Slices are better for single threaded operations.

Comment: i'm ok with that...so if I create a slice with the messages, can I pass that slice into a go routine and continue to consume more message then? I feel like thats maybe a no since the go routine will be working with the slice but them I'm trying to add more to it?? Go rookie here so still learning...

Comment: You have a few options. You could either pass it to a func, wait until it has been pushed to redis and then reuse it. If you want to have parallelism, it is probably easiest to just create a new slice to fill after you pass the first to be emptied into redis.

Comment: hmmm....so if I create a struct of how the slice looks like...how can I create more of them without defining them initially? Not sure if I asked that correctly...

Comment: Check out make. It allows your to create a new slice of a length. They end up heap allocated so you can pass them and then create a new once next time through the loop.